# How to retrieve today's step data for a google fit user using REST API?

Tags: google-fit

We are trying to retrieve the step count of our users in real time. If a user is currently running then we try to fetch the latest value of steps taken. While we are able to retrieve the value of steps one day before today we are not able to do so for the current date.

API URL: https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate

Request Json:

```
{"aggregateBy":[
    {"dataTypeName":"com.google.step_count.delta",
     "dataSourceId":"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"}],
    "bucketByTime":{"durationMillis":86400000},
    "startTimeMillis":1557685800000,
    "endTimeMillis":1557772199999
}
```

Response received:

```
{"bucket":[
    {"startTimeMillis":"1557685800000",
     "endTimeMillis":"1557772199999",
     "dataset":[
         {"dataSourceId":"derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:aggregated",
          "point":[]}
    ]}
]}
```

Comment: If you're asking about Google Fit, it's better to ask about connecting to Google Fit, not going indirectly via Fitbit.

Comment: You can directly link to [try it now](https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/users/dataset/aggregate?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22aggregateBy%22%3A%5B%7B%22dataTypeName%22%3A%22com.google.step_count.delta%22%2C%22dataSourceId%22%3A%22derived%3Acom.google.step_count.delta%3Acom.google.android.gms%3Aestimated_steps%22%7D%5D%2C%22bucketByTime%22%3A%7B%22durationMillis%22%3A86400000%7D%2C%22startTimeMillis%22%3A1557685800000%2C%22endTimeMillis%22%3A1557772199999%7D%7D) with your parameters